# How can we push data to modalviewcontroller similar to pushviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am trying to push data to modalviewcontroller like pushviewcontroller. I have the following code as to call the modalviewcontroller. It will call the view and insert the data as textfield. I save it as a string and then try to insert in the database. In order to store in the database I need to send the unique key to insert the record.

```
-(void) editNote{

TextViewController * vc = [(TextViewController *)[TextViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
[vc release];
}
```

On save option I do call the following method. So now on click of edit button I want to push the record data so that I can use it in save function:

```
-(IBAction) save{

self.description = self.textFieldBeingEdited.text;
NSString *description_query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO NET (ID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('%@','%@');",rec.id, self.description] ;
const char *sql_description = [description_query UTF8String];
sqlite3_exec(db, sql_description, NULL, NULL, NULL);
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
}
```

Has anyone come across such issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the problem, but I gather it has to do with sending data from the parent controller to the modal one at save time?  Easiest way is to use an Objective-C protocol to notify the parent that the save button has been hit, and run everything from there.

Say, for example, I have a class called SaveController, and a RootViewController.

First, I create a protocol called SaveControllerDelegate.h:

```
@protocol SaveControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)saveWasHit:(id)sender;
@end
```

In SaveController.h I can add to the definition:

```
@interface SaveController : UIViewController {
    id <SaveControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SaveControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Now, in RootViewController.h, I add the protocol as a delegate:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <SaveControllerDelegate> {
     ...
}
```

Going back to SaveController, in the .m file I have an IBAction that occurs when the save button is hit.  I modify it to test for the delegate method in RootVewController (or whatever the delegate may be), and if present, call the delegate method and send the data I need:

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonHit:(id)sender
{
     if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(saveWasHit:)])
          [self.delegate saveWasHit:data];
}
```

All that is left now is to edit RootViewController.m to respond to the delegate:

```
saveController = [[SaveController alloc] init];
[saveController setDelegate:self];
```

And implement the protocol:

```
- (void)saveWasHit:(id)sender
{
     //do whatever I need to do with the data from SaveController here.
}
```

Comment: I am calling the method to notify the parent but I am not sure how to pass the data to the parent by notifying the parent.

Comment: OK, so yes.  Definitely served by a protocol.  You can include whatever you need in the method declaration.  Editing my answer to show an example.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to send information from a view controller to the next is to do it at creation. Maybe you can change the `editNote` method into something like this:

```
-(void)editNote:(Note*)note {
    TextViewController * vc = [[TextViewController alloc] initWithNote:note];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

And the save method to something like this:

```
-(IBAction) save{
    self.description = self.textFieldBeingEdited.text;
    NSString *description_query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO NET (ID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('%@','%@');", self.note.id, self.description] ;
    const char *sql_description = [description_query UTF8String];
    sqlite3_exec(db, sql_description, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
}
```

Note that I removed changed `[self parentViewController]` to just `self`. This is a common mistake that no longer works as expected on iOS 5.

Comment: It doesnot find a getter and setter for self.note.id. meaning it gives me error on this line: NSString *description_query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO NET (ID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('%@','%@');", self.note.id, self.description] ; as Request for member in something is not a structure.

Comment: @lifemoveson - Of course it does not! I have no clue how your actual `Note` class is implemented. That was not the point, my point was to show how to use the init method to inject the information you need. You can not expect code snippets given as examples to work by copy and paste.

Comment: True. But didnt find much explanation on your comments to support your code. Anyways I do not have Note class but I have Record class which is an NSObject having various member variables. I want to push one member variable of Record class to TextViewController. And I am not sure what does this line mean : TextViewController * vc = [[TextViewController alloc] initWithNote:note];